# How to get values from form using ngModel in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this error when i use ngModel in input boxes.
**`In .html page`**

```
    <form>
    <div *ngIf="editTitle" class="form-group">
        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="title" required 
        placeholder="title" [(ngModel)]="video.title">
    </div>
        <h3 *ngIf="!editTitle" (click)="onTitleClick()">{{video.title}}</h3>
    </form>
```

This is the details.components.html file and
the last one is the details.components.ts file.

**`In .ts page`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'video-detail',
templateUrl: './video-detail.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./video-detail.component.css'],
inputs: ['video']
})
export class VideoDetailComponent implements OnInit {

private editTitle: boolean = false;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}

ngOnChanges(){
this.editTitle = false;
}

onTitleClick(){
this.editTitle = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Actually what you want dude?

Comment: Can u give detail about error as well?

Comment: Error:
[This is my error](https://i.imgur.com/OV9axIZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app.component.html

```
<form><div *ngIf="editTitle" class="form-group">
  <input type="input" class="form-control" name="title" required 
  placeholder="title" [(ngModel)]="video.title"></div>
  <h3 *ngIf="!editTitle" (click)="onTitleClick()">{{video.title}}</h3>
  </form>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
 AppComponent
 ],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
video: any = {};
private editTitle: boolean = false;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { }
ngOnChanges(){
this.editTitle = false;
}
onTitleClick(){
this.editTitle = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ravi Teja .
It Works :)

Comment: it's my pleasure

Comment: sorry, I can't,
because it shows this error message
[error](https://i.imgur.com/djMuEhK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems are you are getting the input in a wrong way.Try getting the input like this:

```
export class VideoDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() video:object;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

You also have to import the 'Input' module from '@angular/core' like below:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: no this wont work as well
i dont have much knowledge in angular 4,
This is the error image: [image](https://i.imgur.com/OV9axIZ.png)

Comment: Edited my answer: Try importing Input module from angular like this:

    `import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';`